# Stopping the onCreate() method

Tags: java, android

I want to use the `startActivityForResult()` method from the `onCreate()` method of another activity. My problem is that the `onCreate()` does not wait for the result of the new activity (that I called to using `startActivityForResult()`) and therefore the application stops.

Is there a way to tell `onCreate()` to stop until the new activity sends the result?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: So do I. Try to write it more clear and maybe add some code

Comment: I think that the intention is: When starting the app, if the person is not logged in, go to a login activity.

Comment: Show us your `onCreate()` and explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option i've seen to go to a login activity when the user's not yet logged in is the following:

- Create an activity without any attached layout, make this your launcher activity
- In its onCreate, check if the user is logged in.
- If he is logged in -> go to the main activity
- If he is not logged in -> go to login activity which goes to the main activity on successful login

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can use `startActivityForResult()` in `onCreate()` to launch the login activity, but you can't wait for the results. You'll need to move all the code that `onCreate()` would normally do in `onActivityResult()` as that will be called when the login activity completes.